# No Matching function call to templated function with const parameters

Tags: c++, gcc

I have a function that is defined as follows:

```
template < class T> T doSomething(const T value, const T value2, const T value3)
{
   T temp = value;
       //Do stuff
   return temp ;
}
```

in my main, I go to call it as follows:

```
doSomething(12.0, 23.0f, 2.0f);
```

I get an error saying no matching function for call `doSomething(double, float, float)`.

I tried to used const_cast but it didn't seem to fix the issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your function definition uses same type "T" for every of three arguments.
C++ is not able to deduct types in cases like this.

Please choose way to fix:

- Different types for every argument

```
    template<typename A, typename B, typename C>
    A doSomething(const A& value, const B& value2, const C& value3)
    {
        A temp = value;
        //Do stuff
        return temp ;
    }
```

- Explicit template argument on call:

```
    doSomething<int>(12.0, 23.0f, 2.0f);
```

- Explicit type cast for argument on call:

```
    doSomething(12.0, static_cast<double>(23.0f), static_cast<double>(2.0f));
```

Answer (score 8):

It's not about the `const`, but about that `T` cannot be both `double` and `float` at the same time.

If you have a non-template function, one or more parameter can be promoted (or converted) to the parameter type. With a template function, the compiler will have to start by determining what the template type is supposed to be. Here it cannot decide.

Comment: Note that another option is to define three template types T1, T2, T3 for the three function parameters if this makes sense in this case.

Comment: @leemes: Or alternatively, avoid type deduction and call an specific specialization: `doSomething<double>(12.0, 23.0f, 2.0f)` which will enable promotion of the arguments in the same way than non-templates do (i.e. the problem with promoting/not promoting is that type deduction fails, not that it is a template)

Answer (score 0):

When using a templated function, you need to supply the template parameters within angle brackets.

I.e. you need to use `doSomething<float>(12.0, 23.0f, 2.0f);`

Or, at least, if you don't, the compiler has to guess what `T` is, which means when it sees a `double` for the first argument it assumes you mean `doSomething<double>()`

Comment: Anonymous and uncommented downvote. I'd love to know what the problem here is.

Answer (score 0):

When you call like this:

```
doSomething(12.0, 23.0f, 2.0f);
```

then you basically let the compiler to deduce the template argument `T`, from the function arguments. But in the above call, type of all arguments are not same : the first argument`12.0` is `double`, while the rest two arguments are `float` (**Note that `f` in `2.0f`  makes it a `float`, while `2.0` is a `double`.**). Hence the problem, as the compiler is trying to find a function which accepts `double, float, float` as arguments. But there is no such function. And the function template cannot be deduced from the arguments, because `T` has to be **same** for all arguments.

So the solution is, let `T` be deduced as either `double` or `float`:

```
doSomething(12.0f, 23.0f, 2.0f);  //all are float now
```

Or this:

```
doSomething(12.0, 23.0, 2.0);    //all are double now
```

In the first case, `T` is deduced as `float`, and in the second case, `T` is deduced as `double`.

Alternately, you may choose **not** to depend on template argument deduction, by providing template argument as:

```
doSomething<float>(12.0, 23.0f, 2.0f);
```

Or this:

```
doSomething<double>(12.0, 23.0f, 2.0f);
```

Here, in the first case, the 1st argument converts into `float`, and in the second case, 2nd and 3rd argument convert into `double`.